# Flutter SharedPreferences type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<Object>'

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

What I'm trying to do is get SharedPreferences stringList but exception occured. I'm trying to solve it but got stuck (Me noob). Here's the code :

```
  List<String> name;

  getName() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (prefs.containsKey("name")) {
      name = prefs.getStringList("name");
    }
    return [];
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    this.getName();
    super.initState();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return name.isEmpty
        ? Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset("assets/no-data.png"),
                  Text("No Seeds Saved", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        : ListView.builder(
            itemCount: name.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final item = name[index];
              return Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.teal[600],
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(item,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),

                    trailing: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle,
                            color: Colors.redAccent[400]),
                        onPressed: () {}),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
  }
```

Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List')

The following _TypeError was thrown building _BodyBuilder:
type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'List'

Can you help me?

Comment: please do also show the code where you are using the returned value

Comment: Alright edited i'm only use it on widget build nowhere else, is that the problem? the way i use it or something else. I can't figure it out

Comment: @YouOne can you show the code where you save the list?

Comment: Edited mate check it out. Sorry my code is messy

Comment: Is it because before i change to List<String> I use String to store the value with the same key ("name"). I'm new to Shared Preferences is that the case? I'm not sure tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this myself, is because I'm not correctly declare my variable, and also I didn't call the setState itself. Here's what i change

```
List<String> name = [];
  getName() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (prefs.containsKey("name")) {
      setState(() {
        name.addAll(prefs.getStringList("name"));
      });
    }
  }
```

I'm just gonna leave it here in case somebody got the same problem xD